# Why my program in not exiting out of while loop?

Tags: java, input, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Code:

```
int size=0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);     
System.out.println("Enter size of the Graph");
size = in.nextInt();
System.out.println(size);
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    Scanner in2 =new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in2.hasNextInt()){
        int num = in2.nextInt();
        System.out.print("(" + i + "," + num + ")"+",");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("out of the while loop");
}
```

Input & Output:

```
Enter size of the Graph
4
4
2 3 4
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,4),
2 5 6
(1,2),
(1,5),
(1,6),
```

As you can see my program doesn't exists while loop. It still prints the value for i=1.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Then you should enter EOF - or the program will constantly wait for the next feed. Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: linux. How do I do that?

Comment: Provide any character input. That will take you out of the loop.

Comment: Try Control-D. I think that sends EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is constantly waiting for a new feed, in order to terminate it - you should indicate the input was ended (or provide a non `int` input).

To indicate the feed ended - you should provide EOF - which is `ctrl+D` in linux and `ctrl+Z` in windows.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do I do it in eclipse console?

Comment: Same way. feed the EOF to the CLI of the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = in2.nextInt();
```

try adding `in2.nextLine();` after that.

Note:

You shouldn't be doing `new Scanner(System.in);` multiple times.

```
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in); // this is useless just use in
```